# I would recommend FOR / TO you to use this group on Facebook

Tags: complementation, infinitive-clauses

Which one of the following sentences is correct grammatically or structurally?

> 1) "I would recommend **to** you to use this group on Facebook"
>
> 2)  "I would recommend (**empty**) you to use this group on Facebook"
>
> 3)  "I would recommend **for** you to use this group on Facebook"

Comment: Grammatically it is correct, but it would sound a lot more idiomatic if you just left out the *to you*. As for the prepositions, *for* is incorrect and so is the lack of a preposition. You *recommend something **to** someone*.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using this construction? I believe a more idiomatic phrasing would be "I would recommend that you join this group on Facebook". The options you have here seem a bit wordy but you may have a particular reasoning for using them.

Comment: Oh indeed....I would recommend that OP not use any of those constructions.

Comment: Would rather use "I recommend USING. . ." or "I recommend the use of. . ." ('you' is implied in conversations anyway, esp. in this case, where one provides a suggestion to another)

Answer (score 3):

> 1) "I would recommend **to** you to use this group on Facebook"
>
> 2)  "I would recommend (**empty**) you to use this group on Facebook"
>
> 3)  "I would recommend **for** you to use this group on Facebook"

Your first sentence is wrong, and your third sentence is very very unusual if not wrong.

You however can write the following sentences -

> I would recommend you use this group on Facebook.
>
> I would recommend that you use this group on Facebook.
>
> I would recommend using this group on Facebook.
>
> I would recommend using this group on Facebook to you. [UNUSUAL, but may be grammatical]

A short note on the usage of **recommend** -

> Traditional constructions of this transitive verb include those shown
>   in the following types:
>
> **(a)** With direct object -
>
> > He recommended Miss Jones for promotion.
>
> **(b)** Followed by a *that* clause -
>
> > I recommend that you should stay at the George and Dragon.
>
> **(c)** With direct object + a *to* infinitive -
>
> > I recommend you to control your temper.
>
> **(d)** With a subjunctive in the dependent clause -
>
> > the confidential report into Mr John Stalker... recommends that he face a disciplinary tribunal on 10 separate counts — Times, 1986
> >
> > One of the observers from the International Commission of Jurists... had recommended she be approached - N. Gordimer, 1990
>
> Other less common types are shown in the following examples:
>
> **(e)** Ditransitive
>
> > Let me recommend you a little of this pike! — Disraeli, 1826
> >
> > Can you recommend me a nice hotel? — Times, 1985
>
> **(f)** With direct object + plain infinitive
>
> > If you go looking for her, I don't think I can recommend you attend — N. Shakespeare, 1989.

<sub>**Reference -** The New Fowler's Modern English Usage</sub>

Comment: Not that I doubt your source but I find it interesting that a "modern English" book recommends constructions like "that you *should* stay" and "you *to* control". I find both "should" and "to" to be unnecessary in these constructions.

Comment: @Catija I have seen many threads here about this particular verb, and I believe there is a significant difference about the use of **recommend** between two versions of English used on both ends of Atlantic. What I gathered is that the *to-infinitive* version is not very common in AmE, and they are happy to stick to *that-clause*. But in COCA I have found both the constructions. And about the use of *should*, I have no idea :-)

Comment: So, is Fowler's for BrE? That might be worth noting.

Comment: @Catija That is what I think. And editor of this new edition is Burchfield, but the name of this book still bears the name of Fowler. Both of them are Oxford's lexicographers. Fowler is from London, and Burchfield was born in New Zealand.

Comment: @Man_From_India: are you sure 'attend' is a bare infinitive in your last sentence? I would rather say it is a present subjunctive…

Comment: @user58319 that is what the book says. Anyway, I think, here both what you said and what the book said are the same thing. No real difference it will offer to the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

*To* is used after a verb in the following situations:

- to identify the indirect object (*Give the ball to Jim*.)
- to express direction an activity is "pointed" if the verb expresses motion (*I walked to the store*).
- if a phrase following a verb starts with an infinitive, it might start with the word *to* (i.e. *I tried to go to the park*).

So you cannot say *I recommend to you to go to Facebook*, but you can say *I recommend to go to Facebook*.

A clause can follow *recommend* if the what you are recommending isn't a simple object or noun.  *That* is the conjunction that would be used to introduce the clause, but it may be omitted.

So something like

> I recommend [that] you go to Facebook.

will work too.  That's why you can get away with apparently omitting the preposition, though it's really *that* that you are leaving out.

*For X* can be used to express that X is a desired result or reason, e.g. *I asked for two of them*, *I want for them to stop being stupid* - or (archaically) *I did not go to the ball, for my evil stepsister was there.*  So this works with *recommend*.

Comment: "*I recommend to go to Facebook.*" This sounds like a very poor construction to me. Can you show a source that says this is acceptable?

Comment: Seems like there's many sources when I search saying not to follow *recommend* with an infintive - to use a gerund instead.  Yep, I'm wrong - though OP's example 1 is really wrong.